# Custom LengthMenu in datatable

Tags: jquery, jsp, datatables

Currently I am using Script,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        "lengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, -1], [10, 25, 50, "All"]], "iDisplayLength" : 25
    });
});
```

HTML,

```
<input type="text" id=change />
```

I want to change lengthMenu. User can enter number manually in above textbox. By using input value I want to set it to lengthMenu.

For example if user enter 3 in text input then change lengthMenu to 3. So datatable will show 3 records per page.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, Do you have some code you can post so we can see what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

Try the [page.len() API  method](https://datatables.net/reference/api/page.len%28%29):

```
var length = $("#change").val();
table.page.len(length).draw();
```

Answer (score 1):

To make a custom page length we should have a Select Option form as follows

```
                    <select class="form-control form-control-sm rounded-0 col-12" id="rowsPerPage">
                        <option selected>Choose...</option>
                        <option value="10">10</option>
                        <option value="20">20</option>
                        <option value="30">30</option>
                    </select>
```

to access the values of selected option write a on change function to select option as follows

`dataDatatable` is the variable we assign to datatable

```
var dataDatatable = $('#vendorDatatable').DataTable({})
```

```
        $('#rowsPerPage').on('change', function() {
            let row = $("#rowsPerPage").val() 
            dataDatatable.page.len(row).draw();
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

(1)Do not use datatables' default lengthMenu,write a html input and css it to fit to your page.

(2)Bind the event maybe as:'keyup' to your input,invoke the event provided by datatables:[event-length](https://datatables.net/reference/event/length).